# Equivalents Triethylamine in Swern-oxidation

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, organic-oxidation

[image]

Hey folks,

so I've been wondering why the use of 5 equivalents of Et3N in this case of a Swern-oxidation is necessary. I have done this reaction succesfully quite a few times now, but all the literature uses 5 equivalents as well. I am fully aware of the mechanism (shown below). I can explain one eq. for the HCl that emerges in step one:[image]
And in the second step we need the base to form the sulfurylide:
[image]

but this should not be a equilibrium as the Ylide has no net charge and in my opinion is more stable. 
If it were to just enhance the reactivity a bit, I'd think that 2 more eq. (so 3 eq. in total) are sufficient.

I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: Have you tried the reaction with less equivs?  Do you need extra to raise the pH especially in the presence of carbon dioxide?  Is some trapped as a hemi-aminal?  Just guesses ...

Comment: 3 equivalents of Et3N is stoichiometric. If the ylid is reversibly protonated by Et3N-HCl, why not use excess Et3N? It certainly isn't detrimental. Note that each successive reagent is in excess.

Comment: If isn't broke don't fix it! Et3N is cheap.